# Как перенести проект с JDK 8 на более новую версию и использовать Jlink?

Tags: java, ide, модули

Есть проект на JDK 8. Хочется перенеси его на более новую версию и создать JRE для проекта. Я не нашел ни одного гайда, как этом можно сделать при использовании среды разработки. То есть, есть куча синтетических примеров, где можно создать папки

src/main/java/org.site.module1
src/main/java/org.site.module2

Потом в каждом модуле создать необходимые пакеты, потом вызвать различные команды для компиляции и сборки. Но все это совсем никак не связано с реальными ситуациями. Имея проект в Idea с Maven структура папок совершенно другая и ни одна из команд естественно не работает. Да и создать структуру папок как в примерах не получится, Idea не разрешит вам даже создать папку в нужном, казалось бы, месте.

Может кто подсказать полезные гайды как можно оперировать модулями через IDE? Или может у кого-то есть готовый проект на гитхабе

Answer (score 0):

Вам совершенно незачем изменять стандартную схему директорий. Вам нужно лишь сделать так, чтобы каждый Java модуль был так же и Maven проектом, то есть IntelliJ IDEA модулем со своим `pom.xml` и `module-info.java`. Для работы с `jlink` в Maven есть эксперементальный плагин [maven-jlink-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jlink-plugin/).